# How to correctly combine strings and variables when applying ng-class via an expression?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

When my app initializes, the following implementation of `ng-class` works as expected and the class name is correctly applied. However, when the value of `person.status` changes during run time, the class stays the same.

Here's my code:

```
ng-class="{ 'avatar--{{ person.status }}' : myBool }"
```

How can I change the formatting so that when the value of `person.status` changes, so does my class?

*Example: if `person.status` is set to `online` when the app initializes, the applied class is `avatar--online`. However if their status changes to `offline` in the current session, the class remains `avatar--online`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried to use an angular expression in the class name portion of the ng-class. but you could achieve what you want with this implementation

```
ng-class="{'avatar--online': person.status == 'online',
           'avatar--offline': person.status == 'offline'}"
```

basically you can set two conditions in your ng-class implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: in case of few statuses (2-3) this is the best option, probably a bit to verbose in case of several statuses.

Answer (score 3):

If you can find a way around using 'mybool', try this:

```
ng-class="'avatar--' + person.status"
```

Working code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = ['blue', 'green'];
  $scope.color = $scope.colors[0];


});
```

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.prefix--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.prefix--green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c for c in colors"></select>
  <div class="mydiv" ng-class="'prefix--'+color"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't end up using this solution but I did find it useful. Thank you!